# Is there a way to parse out HTML Comments on the Server side (PHP or MySQL)

Tags: html, parsing, comments, server-side

We need a way to remove HTML comments when displayed to the user but not to the developer.
I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you removing comments from your own PHP pages, or from someone else's markup you have in a string?

For the latter, use an HTML parser, as suggested by Gumbo. Don't use regex to parse HTML, because it can't. (I need to bind a hotkey to that sentence. Every third question on SO is trying to parse HTML with a regex. It is not a good idea.)

If you mean the former, just use PHP comments instead of HTML ones and you won't have to do any post-processing:

```
<?php /* blah */ ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$html = eregi_replace("<!--[^>]*-->", "", $html);
```

Or using preg_replace, as mentioned below:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/", "", $html);
```

And, yes, either way, comment delimiters embedded in strings will cause problems.

Comment: What about `<p title="<!--">foo--></p>`?

Comment: ereg is deprecated PHP regex functionality due for removal in PHP 6.  Use preg_replace, it's faster anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to use a parser like [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument), traverse the DOM tree and remove all comment nodes. Or you build a parser on your own.